# PHP image validation not working

Tags: php, file-upload, pdo

I am working on a CMS for my site. I've successfully created created the "**new-post.php**" page & added some conditions for image type & size validation. That works perfectly. I've the same page for **updating** the post. But the condition is not working on this page. It shows the "**invalid image**" alert even I upload an image with valid extension. What's wrong with my code?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
if(!$stmt)
            {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' style='margin-top: 20px;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign'></span> <strong>Post has not been updated.</strong></div><a href='dashboard?new' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style'margin-top: 50px;'>Take me there again.I'll try again.</a>";
            }
            else
            {
                if($image_type=="pimage/jpeg" OR $image_type=="pimage/jpg" OR $image_type=="pimage/png" OR $image_type=="pimage/bmp" OR $image_type=="pimage/gif")
                {
                    $stmt->execute();
                    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, "uploads/$image");
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-success' style='margin-top: 20px;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign'></span> <strong>Post has been updated successfully.</strong></div>
                        <a href='dashboard?view' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg' style'margin-top: 50px;'>Show me</a>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('Invalid image');</script>";
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo error. It should be "image" not "pimage"

```
if($image_type=="image/jpeg" OR $image_type=="image/jpg" OR $image_type=="image/png" OR $image_type=="image/bmp" OR $image_type=="image/gif")
```

Comment: "pimage" is the name of input type file

Comment: Whisch refers to "post image"

Comment: Image type should be image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png. There will not be name of the field in the image type.

Comment: It's  what i was looking for.Till now, i considered that the name of field comes in **image** /jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120425/discussion-between-anonoymous-and-rahul-patel).